# Как переместить сайдбар в середину контента на мобильной версии?

Tags: css

Суть вопроса в заголовке, вот [наглядный пример того, что хочу сделать.](https://codepen.io/andrej-rusinas/pen/PoqPrro)

Проблема в том, что для desktop версии должно быть две колонки - content и sidebar, но чтобы переместить sidebar media-запросами, он должен быть внутри content. :(

Пытался сделать desktop версию с sidebar внутри content, однако получалось следующее:

```
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
    grid-template-areas: "content sidebar" "content sidebar" .... // И вот так столько раз, сколько будет строк в сетке (grid row), а их количество неизвестно. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
$( ".sidebar" ).insertAfter( ".block" );
```

Где ".block" - элемент после которого будет расположен сайдбар.
Вы можете исполнять это при разрешении меньше чем сколько-то:

```
if ($(window).width() > 765) {
        $( ".sidebar" ).insertAfter( ".block" );
      }
```

Можно исполнять эту функцию при загрузке и ресайзе, все должно работать.